# Programar peticiones HTTP en Windows de forma automática

Tags: php, windows, cron, cronjobs

Tengo un script en PHP en un servidor local montado en Windows Server 2008 y lo que necesito es ejecutarlo por ejemplo cada 3 minutos. Al estar el script en un servidor local, sería suficiente con programar una petición HTTP al script como si de un navegador se tratase, pero sin abrir una ventana de chrome u otros, ya que esto se realiza cada 3 minutos y se colapsaría el servidor. Ej: `http://localhost/dir/script.php`

He probado usar PowerShell junto al programador de tareas de Windows para hacerlo pero al ejecutar el comando `Invoke-WebRequest` de la solución que mencionan en [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/829328), pero me aparece este error:

> El término 'Invoke-WebRequest' no se reconoce como nombre de un
> cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.

¿Alguien conoce un software o alternativa que permita realizar esto o la solución al error anterior?

Comment: ¿Exactamente que Windows es? ¿Que es lo que has intentado? (_mostranos como creaste la tarea_) ¿Cual es el error que recibís? (_mostranos el error_)

Comment: Quiere que llame al URL como si fuera un browser?  O solamente quiere que arrancar el PHP?  Si es el primero, PowerShell con Task Manager es la respuesta.  Si es el otro, tiene que instalar PHP para Windows.

Comment: @Marcos y @ Duston, he actualizado la pregunta con vuestras dudas, muchísimas gracias!